# Residue of complex function $f$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

> Let $D=\{z\in \mathbb{C} :|z|<2 \}$ and $f$ be a function on $D$ which is analytic at every point except $z=1$ and also it has a simple pole at $z=1$. Suppose that
> $$f(z)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n}z^{n} , \qquad |z|<1.$$
> Show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_{n}=-c$ where  $c$ is residue of $f$ at $z=1$.

My approach is that, define a Laurent expansion of f around $z=1$ and compare Taylor expansion and Laurent expansion at $z=1/2$  and compute $\lim a_{n}$.

Comment: Hint: $f(z)=\frac c{z-1}+g(z)$, where $g$ has a removable singularity at $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler method uses the fact that **reducing the residue of a simple pole to zero removes the singularity entirely.**

To implement this, render

$f(z)=g(z)+\dfrac{c}{z-1}$

where the residue of $g$ at $1$ is reduced to zero leaving $g$ analytic there. We then have the following Taylor series expansions:

$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$

$g(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nz^n$

$\dfrac{c}{z-1}=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty cz^n$

$\color{blue}{a_n=b_n-c}$

Then $g$ is analytic through all of $|z|\le1$ forcing the Taylor series for $g$ to converge at $z=1$, $\therefore b_n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$.  It follows that $a_n=b_n-c\to-c$.

Comment: clever idea... hmph